# How to implement a Checkbox Group in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using pyqtgraph in python for some graphing capability. I've added a few checkboxes:

```
check1 = QtGui.QCheckBox(win)
check2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(win)
check3 = QtGui.QCheckBox(win)
check4 = QtGui.QCheckBox(win)

check1.setText("Checkbox 1")
check2.setText("Checkbox 2")
check3.setText("Checkbox 3")
check4.setText("Checkbox 4")

gridLayout.addWidget(check1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
gridLayout.addWidget(check2, 1, 4, 1, 1)
gridLayout.addWidget(check3, 1, 6, 1, 1)
gridLayout.addWidget(check4, 1, 8, 1, 1)
```

How can I enforce it so the user can only have 1 checkbox checked at any given time? I attempted this in the update function:

```
if check1.isChecked():
    check2.setChecked(False)
    check3.setChecked(False)
    check4.setChecked(False)

if check2.isChecked():
    source = 2
    check1.setChecked(False)
    check3.setChecked(False)
    check4.setChecked(False)
....
```

That sort of works, but it seems off. I think since it's in the `update` function, it's causing some issues. Is there a way to access the event that fires when you click the checkbox? I think it would be best to do it in some kind of event method instead of checking in the update method.

Comment: This is really a pyqt question; pyqtgraph does not implement the check/radio widgets.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I'm new to pyqtgraph. I was able to solve my issue with my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong tools for the job. I solved it with Radio Buttons, not sure why I didn't think of that sooner.

My example is the same except:

```
radio1 = QtGui.QRadioButton(win)
radio1.setText("Radio 1")
gridLayout.addWidget(radio1, 1, 2, 1, 1)

if radio1.isChecked():
  # Do stuff
```